# React-Native (or JS) Decode Base64 to ZIP File

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption, encoding, decoding

I am working on an application that *[is trying to]* optimize storing images and videos in the AWS while also considering retrieval of the data.

I do this in 2 steps: **A. Store the data into AWS** & **B. Retrieve the data from AWS**.
The current problem I am trying to solve exists in **B: Step 3**. I cannot correctly decode Base64 into a Zip File.

**A.** I store the data in a 6 step process to ensure that the data is compressed as much as possible (cost-savings) and encrypted so only the user can access it (encryption).

1. Attain images / videos from user

   Reason: User Data Selection

```js
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
    if(response.assets) {
        const assets = response.assets;
        completeCallback(assets);
    }
    else if(response.errorCode) {
        const message = response.errorMessage;
        console.log(message);
    }
    else {
        cancelCallback();
    }
});
```

2. Store images from original location into Document Directory

   Reason: Consolidated Location to Zip

```js
static async copyFilesToDocumentDirectory(urls) {
    var path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/media`;
    let existDir = await RNFS.exists(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/media').then(boolean => boolean);
    if(!existDir) { RNFS.mkdir(path); };
    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
        return RNFS.exists(url)
            .then((status) => {
                if(status) {
                    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    var newPath = path + "/" + filename;
                    return RNFS.copyFile(url, newPath);
                };
            });
    }));
};
```

3. Zip up documents

   Reason: Should reduce file size but isn't necessarily in every case

```js
static zipDocumentDirectory = async () => {
    var sourcePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/media`;
    var targetPath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/myFile.zip`;
        
    return await zip(sourcePath, targetPath);
}
```

4. Encode Zip as base64

   Encode data so I can encrypt it

```js
AWS.getPresignedURLPut(DBKey, passCode, 
    async (url) => {
        await RNFS.readFile(zipURI, 'base64')
        .then(res => {
                // Next Section
                ...
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(`Err: ${err}`)
        }
    );
```

5. Encrypt base64

   Reason: E2E Encryption

```
const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(res, ENKey).toString();
const json =
{
    'DBKey': DBKey,
    'PassCode': passCode,
    'base64data': encryptedData
};
// Store data in Next Section
```

6. Store in Database

   Reason: Database Storage

```js
AWS.storeJSONToAWSS3PresignedURL(json, url, onComplete);
```

---

**B.** I retrieve the data in the same manner, just the reverse order.

1. Retrieve Encrypted Base64 from Database

   Reason: Get Original Data

```js
AWS.getJSONFromAWSS3PresignedURL(url); //returns Base64 String
```

2. Decrypt to Original Base64

   Reason: Need to Attain Original Base64

```js
/* Decryption */
const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, endToEndEncryptionKey)
originalBase64 = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

3. Decode Base64 to Zip File **PROBLEM**

   Reason: Need the original Zip File Containing Videos/Photos

```js
static writeBase64ToDocumentDirectory = async (base64) => {
    var path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/myFile.zip`;
    const blob = b64toBlob(base64);
    const file = new File([blob], path, { type: 'application/x-zip-compressed' });
    console.log(`F:`);
    console.log(file);
    console.log(`B:`);
    console.log(blob);
};

const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
    const byteCharacters = global.atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
  
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
  
      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }
  
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
  
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}

/*
F:
{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "9341bc78-11e7-428c-96c4-e761dc47f75a", "lastModified": undefined, "name": "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/986B087C-A19A-4DDA-9180-831B4EDE89B9/Documents/myFile.zip", "offset": 0, "size": 1948698, "type": "application/x-zip-compressed"}}

B:
{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "66b4e283-5a26-4684-a6f7-49f3615c8509", "lastModified": undefined, "offset": 0, "size": 1948698, "type": ""}}
*/
```

4. Last step is to unzip the file but it doesn't exist.

```js
await RNFS.readDir(`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}`)
.then((result) => {
    console.log(`Zip Path: ${result} -- ${result.length}`);
    console.log(result);
});

/*
Zip Path:  -- 0
[]
*/
```

**PROBLEM:**
I cannot seem to find a way to convert the base64 to a decoded zip file.

**Working Validation:**
I know this can work as I can decode the base64 using [this](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file) website. But, I cannot reproduce the code to do the same local to the device.

Comment: Are `res` in A.5 and `originalBase64` in B.2 identical? From which library is `base64toBlob()` or if user defined how is the implementation?

Comment: @Topaco Yes, res in A.5 and `originalBase64` in B.2 are identical. It is a user implementation and I forgot to add it. :P I have since done so

Comment: To take it a step further, I have used both the A.5 an B.2 results in the website at the bottom of the post, https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file, and got attained the same zip file.

Answer (score 2):

```
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
    const byteCharacters = global.atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
  
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
  
      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }
  
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
  
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
};
```

After you have converted the Base64 string to a Blob, you can write the Blob to a file using the File constructor and the writeFile method from the react-native-fs library.

Comment: I already use this (albeit, I just added this, accidentally). Reference B.3.

Comment: And I still receive the same error.